# 'Decodable' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context

Tags: ios, json, xcode9-beta, swift4, gloss

I am using [Gloss](https://github.com/hkellaway/Gloss) for JSON decoding with Xcode9 beta 1 Swift 4. I am facing following issue:

[Xcode 9 beta screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPH39.png)

It was working like charm in Xcode8.3.3 with Swift 3 but since I have upgraded to latest Xcode9, it has stopped working. I am guessing that Gloss decoding has a conflict with Swift 4 JSON decoding. Did anyone face the similar issue? Appreciate any help in this regard.

Comment: I recommend to drop Gloss and use the built-in functionality of Swift 4.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Swift 4 encoding has performance barrier over large data. So kind of looking for a work around as it's still in beta.

Comment: Did you try to include the module name, e.g. `Gloss.Decodable` ?